# pARK working on iPhone 3GS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, augmented-reality, core-motion

I have been building on top of the iphone augmented reality framework found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/pARk/Introduction/Intro.html) 
but sadly, on mobiles without gyro (namely the 3GS) it doesn't work (as it states.)

Does anyone know of a fix to make it work with the motion sensors and compass heading instead ? Or would anyone be so bounty-hungry to provide the codes to a such framework ?

I will need a way to either make the vectors work, and if it is not possible, I will need to push through and just use heading only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CoreMotion do work in devices like 3GS. However, this Framework pARk is for devices with gyroscopes (Runtime Requirements: iPad 2 or iPhone 4 running `iOS 5.0` or later)

Gyroscope is a fundamental piece of inertial navigation systems (INS) and thus without it you'll have a severe loss in precision.

Check the paper: "[Usability of apple iPhones for inertial navigation systems](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6139701)" for a comparison of the performance of iPhone 3GS and iPhone 4. The author's conclusion is:

> However, the tests show that even with the use of filters
>   it is challenging to build a precise INS using sensors from
>   common devices because of their inaccuracies and high
>   error rate. The results show that the iPhone 4 can provide
>   tolerable results for a short time, but then the deviation
>   becomes too high because of the error rate. Currently we are
>   implementing a multi-dimensional Kalman filter to examine
>   possible enhancements. Furthermore we try to improve the
>   system by using more sensors from the iPhone 4, e.g. light
>   sensors and camera.

I believe you should think your app to support only iPhone4 or newer.